# find images in div except certain child div

Tags: jquery

Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Xhqz9/

I'm trying to find all images inside `<div id="primary" />` except the images located inside any `<div class="nohover" />`, which is always a child element, and do a hover effect on those images.

```
<div id="primary">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75">
    <div class="nohover">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75">
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75">
    <div class="nohover">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75">
    </div>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
var postImgsRed = $('#primary').find('img');
postImgsRed.each(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});

var postImgsHover = $("#primary > :not(.nohover)").find("img");
postImgsHover.each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    })
});​
```

My hover function is not executing correctly.  it won't do the effect on the 1st or 3rd image, as I want to do.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var postImgsRed = $('#primary').find('img');
postImgsRed.each(function() {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});

var postImgsHover = $("#primary > img");
postImgsHover.each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    })
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xhqz9/1/

Note: This works for your example. You need to change it up if you can have images that aren't direct descendants of `#primary` match the condition with `$("#primary img").not(".nohover img")`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector and filter out the ones under .nohover

```
$('#primary img').not('.nohover img')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HDuRq/

[Fiddle with your hover effects](http://jsfiddle.net/rnTb8/)

Comment: -1 because .nohover is not on img elements, it's on div elements. basic idea is right though, using .not()

Comment: What do you mean?  i'm filtering out images under .nohover... there's a space between specifying a descendant

Comment: @Derek No. `img` is a descendant of `.novhover` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find direct `img` descendents of `#primary`:

```
$('#primary > img').each();
```

Answer (score 0):

use the selector:

```
$('#primary > img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `children()` instead of `find()` as it will only select the direct descendants of your node instead of any descendants : http://api.jquery.com/children/

```
$('#primary').children('img');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use .not() to exclude elements with the .nohover class:

```
$('#primary div').not('div.nohover').find('img')...
```

Comment: This definitely won't work since .not() filters out current elements in the collection.. which ('div.nohover') does not come up in the $('#primary') collection..